# How to learn hash type while knowing password as a plain-text format and its hash value?

Tags: hash

I have a hash string and also its plain-text format string. But I don't know which encryption algorithm is used. How can I learn this? I used a lot of hash type checker. But all of these cannot identify the hash type or identify wrongly.

Hash string is: zDWawT8izqRMdAQVsFUvZg==

Plain text format is: 123123a%

Which algorithm is used?

Comment: I suggest creating a 'rainbow table' of sorts, with each line a hash of a different algorithm.

Comment: It's not any of these:

Adler32 075d01b3

CRC32 46fb3986

Haval f32ee108a58a857a2112dcfbad82af25

MD2 cd1f1ccde36c1c6fd0e3bb53b8c0233e

MD4 ad2b7640ddc4be4e319587758e20d7a6

MD5 983199ad979bcc1c298a0fe306feae36

RipeMD128 9e0159fcf4d90ef0c8fdde2d085b21dc

RipeMD160 eca421e0fabd93a8934ed5e80fa32c1cc294f226

SHA-1 4150f1d2842a78df6fc9bd69a10ed2e6d223c1db

SHA-256 8eda91a9c9b5b4bcf2ec3d1f12e77c71f3c6fe9b801a8db75e94e6ff68a99271

Comment: One approach is to use something like the cyberchef which has a "generate all hashes" option https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Generate_all_hashes()&input=MTIzMTIzYSU . from that it doesn't look like any basic ones, but it could well have a salt or similar that would make it hard to determine

Comment: Flagged this due to the fact that this question appears to be a duplicate as mentioned by S.L Barth.

Comment: That's a base64 string, @Hasan. You'll need to decode it to hex first, then compare that to the hash results.

Comment: `>>> hexlify(s.decode("base64")) -->
'cc359ac13f22cea44c740415b0552f66'`
Could be salted and all, but here's the hexdigest for convenience.

Comment: @RandomHash I'm not sure how a rainbow table would help in any way.

Comment: @forest - indeed, not quite the correct terminology for a list of all possible hash values, for a single input. Remind me, what is that called again?

Comment: @RandomHash I'm not sure if that has a name if it's for a single input. It sounds like it would be some sort of hash table. Although there would be no need to precompute anything since it wouldn't gain any performance advantage.

Answer (score -1):

This does not look like a hash. It looks like base64 "uuencoding". It might be a uuencoding *of* the hash. It uudecodes to 16 bytes of binary data, so likely a hash that produces 128 bit output.

Try all the hashing algorithms with 128 bit output, then base64 encode the *binary* (not ascii hex representation) value of the hash output, and see if you get a match.

Comment: Base64 and uuencode are completely different formats.